# How to start MQ queue manager automatically on Windows boot?

Tags: windows-server-2012, websphere

I'm using WebSphere MQ 7.5 on Windows server 2012.

My queue manager's "Startup" setting is already set to "Automatic", but still the queue manager does not start on boot.

What am I missing?

*p.s. Can a moderator please create a [websphere-mq](/questions/tagged/websphere-mq) tag, please?*

Comment: "Can a moderator please create a websphere-mq tag, please? " please ask this on meta. Also please provide description for this new tag.

Comment: [websphere] has only 18 questions but 9 followers.  An orphan tag for mq isn't likely to attract answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
%windir%\system32\services.msc
```

and verify that the `IBM WebSphere MQ` service is set to automatic start for `Windows`.

It could be that the service is actually started but then prematurely goes down due to some error. Check the `WebSphere` logs and the [Windows Event log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Service `IBM WebSphere MQ (75)` startup type is already set to automatic.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it seems to crash on startup. `Error AMQ6119 (internal MQ error)`, no comments, `MQM Function Stack: zsllpiStartQM, zutUpdateQMXADLLEntry`...